# Yii2 removing white space left and right of each post data?

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

Function is:-
want to use trim() method in beforeAction controller for removing white space left and right of each post data ?

```
public function beforeAction($action)
{
     Yii::$app->request->post() // I want to trim all post data
     return parent::beforeAction($action);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Better way to use `trim` in model rules like this

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['here_field_name'], 'filter', 'filter' => 'trim'],
    ];
}
```

or

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['here_field_name'], 'trim'],
    ];
}
```

Refer [Yii2 Core Validators](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/tutorial-core-validators)

Comment: can I use your shared rules on controller ?
Yes, I have fixed it via adding code on web.php. I used following code to trim each post data
'on beforeAction' => function ($event) {
           $_POST = filter_var($_POST, \FILTER_CALLBACK, ['options' => 'trim']);
    }

Answer (score 0):

I used following code to trim each post data

```
'on beforeAction' => function ($event) { $_POST = filter_var($_POST, \FILTER_CALLBACK, ['options' => 'trim']); }
```